# how to prevent destroying fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

in my Activity, i load 4 fragments by code bellow:

```
 supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .replace(R.id.frame, fragmentList[0])
                    .commit()
```

but the problem is each fragment has lots of data and should load lots of data from the server. and it takes a little much. I want that my fragment doesn't be destroyed when I change them to prevent loading data again. how can I do that? is there any way that the fragments just be hidden and not destroyed and by loading, they just show up?

Answer (score 1):

instead of replace use `.add(containerId, newFragment)` and then `.hide(currentFragment)`

edit:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                        .add(R.id.frame, fragmentList[0])
                        .hide(fragmentList[1]) // assumed that fragmentList[1] is your current fragment
                        .commit()
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't get it. can you give me an example of the use of that, by considering first load and secondary load? @Hooman

Comment: i changed the answer

Answer (score 0):

A UI controller like an Activity or Fragment should not be responsible for requesting and loading data. Create a ViewModel that handles the loading of the data and the reference to it. Your fragments that need it can observe the data through a LiveData.

If you pass the Activity instance to the ViewModelProvider, the ViewModel will live for as long as the Activity does, not just for the Fragment's life:

```
// in onViewCreated():
model = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

If you're using KTX:

```
// a fragment class property:
val model: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()
model =
```